# sorting data for complex shapes - python

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, plot

Say i have a given set of points that i import using a CSV. My ultimate goal is to grab this XY data, convert it to polar form, find a smoothing line and finally obtain a residual plot  (between the polar plot and the smoothed line).

(in the code you will see that i centered the xy data before converting to polar)

So initially i used the data and found that the data seemed to be jumbled. hence when i convert to polar and find the residual it looked terrible.
i figured that i needed to sort the data beforehand.

Comparisons for what i need to see (roughly) when i plot xy and what i do see when i plot xy are shown in the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jelk5.jpg

My code for import and plotting the data is here:

```
def cart2pol(x, y):
 rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
 phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
 return(rho, phi)

def extract():
 filename = "C:/Users/dsfsdf/Dropbox/rthrth/xy50.csv"
 data = {}
 data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=',',dtype= float)
 block.append(data)
 x.append(block[0][:,0])
 y.append(block[0][:,1])

extract()
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
y = y-min(y[0,:]) #To centre it on the y-axis
x = x - ((max(x[0,:])+min(x[0,:]))/2)  #To centre it on the x-axis
xf = x[0,:]
yf = y[0,:]
[rf,th] = cart2pol(xf,yf)
thf = th-np.pi / 2 

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(yf,xf)
plt.xlabel('y')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(thf,rf)
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$')
plt.ylabel('r')
```

I've tried this code for clockwise sorting that i found on another thread and it helps quite alot,but doesn't completely correct the issue:

```
def clockwise(x,y):
 cx = np.mean(x)
 cy = np.mean(y)
 a = np.arctan2(y - cy, x - cx)
 order = a.ravel().argsort()
 x = x[order]
 y = y[order]
 return np.vstack([x,y])
```

heres the plot you get for that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZhPz.jpg

What is wrong with this process? is all i need to fix the data sorting? should i be sorting xy data --> then going polar or go polar then sort? 
How can i get sort the data so that the plot will connect correctly?

Thanks for the help

Comment: In Python, indentation matters.  A lot.  And if this about Python, why the R tag?

Comment: One of the problems with that sorting is that your curve is not a single-valued function (in the math sense) of the angle, that is f(theta) has more than one value.  This is the source of the 'filled' regions where the plot is going back-and-forth.

Comment: yeah you are right. although it seems like the sorting algorithm i used actually almost fixed it. if there a more robust version of that, it may completely remove all 'filled' regions